# How to save in app main directory sqlite file in swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite, directory

I have this function:

```
 func takeDatabase() -> FMDatabase {
    let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    let path = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")

    let database = FMDatabase(path: path)
    // println(path)
    if !database.open() {
        println("Unable to open database")

    }

    return database
}
```

I want to change the path, to be in main directory of my app. How can I do this? I try a lot, but with no results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First You have to Know The Concept OF [sandboxing](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/application-security-on-apple-ios-mobile-devices.html). after reading the docment you got idea . After what you want comment Here.

- this [Link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iOS_4_(iPhone)) will help you to working with directories